# Ambiguous input redirect error in csh

Tags: csh

```
echo "yes" | my_program < input_file
```

I'm getting `Ambiguous input redirect` error in csh. How to solve this?

Comment: `|` redirects the input.  `<` also redirects the input.  Pick one.

Comment: Using both `|` and `<` works in `bash`.

Comment: How do you want to solve it?  _Which is the redirection that you actually want to do?_  We are not telepathic.  You have to _tell us_ what input you actually want to send to the program.

Comment: I have added a sample `expect` script to my answer, I can refine it somewhat to your needs if you could specify what the question is that you get asked by `my_program` and which you want to send "yes" as reply to...

Answer (score 1):

According to a comment left by op, `my_program` sometimes expects a response to a `yes|no` question.

This means the op wants to use `expect`, use the right tools for the task; from the man page of expect:

> Expect  is a program that "talks" to other interactive programs
>   according to a script.  Following the script, Expect knows what can be
>   expected from a program and what the correct response should be.  An
>   interpreted language provides branching and high-level control
>   structures to direct the dialogue.  In addition, the user can take
>   control and interact directly when desired, afterward returning
>   control to the script.

Now, I do not know what the prompt says that the op's program puts out, but, assuming it starts with `Are you sure` the following should work:

```
#!/usr/bin/expect

spawn  bash -c "my_program < /tmp/input"

expect {
     "Are you sure" {
     send "yes"
     }
     eof
}
```

You simply create a shell script with the above and execute it instead of the command you want to execute.

More generic expect script, wants four arguments: "program", "input file", "question", "your reply" (where the latter two are optional, if "question" does not come, no "reply" will be sent and the script will just quit successfully):

```
#!/usr/bin/expect
set arg1 [lindex $argv 0]
set arg2 [lindex $argv 1]
set arg3 [lindex $argv 2]
set arg4 [lindex $argv 3]

spawn  bash -c "$arg1 < $arg2"

expect {
     "$arg3" {
     send "$arg4"
     }
     eof
}
```

use as follows (assuming you copied the above into `myexp.sh`):

```
./myexp.sh "my_program" "/tmp/input" "yes"
```

In general, if you want multiple sources of input you use a here document to sort them.

```
my_program <<EOF
`cat input_file`
yes
EOF
```

Another option for multiple input:

```
echo 'yes' >> input_file
```

or using a temp file:

```
echo 'yes' > /tmp/myfile$$.txt
cat input_file >> /tmp/myfile$$.txt
my_program < /tmp/myfile$$.txt
```

It all really depends on what you want to achieve.

EDIT (From the comments):

```
( echo 'yes'; cat input_file;) | my_program
```

works as well ... I find heredocs *easier* to read, YMMV.

Comment: You mean `(echo 'yes'; cat input_file)  | my_program`, right ?

Comment: csh reports `{: Command not found.` on my box ... upvoted your initial comment as it put me on the way to another option ;-)

Comment: Apologies I missed the [tag:csh] tag on the question

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're piping the stdout of `echo` to the stdin of `my_program`...

```
echo "yes" | my_program
```

... while at the same time you are **also** feeding the content of `input_file` to the stdin of `my_program`:

```
my_program < input_file
```

A process (in this case `my_program`) can't be fed on stdin from two different sources, so you need to choose which one must provide the input.

Comment: my_program sometimes gives out a yes/no prompt. That is why I'm doing echo "yes" so that it takes whenever the prompt comes up.  How do I achieve this?